# Get latest value looked up from other dataframe

Tags: python, merge

My first data frame

```
product=pd.DataFrame({
    'Product_ID':[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,101],
    'Product_name':['Watch','Bag','Shoes','Smartphone','Books','Oil','Laptop','New Watch'],
    'Category':['Fashion','Fashion','Fashion','Electronics','Study','Grocery','Electronics','Electronics'],
    'Price':[299.0,1350.50,2999.0,14999.0,145.0,110.0,79999.0,9898.0],
    'Seller_City':['Delhi','Mumbai','Chennai','Kolkata','Delhi','Chennai','Bengalore','New York']
})
```

My 2nd data frame has transactions

```
customer=pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'name':['Olivia','Aditya','Cory','Isabell','Dominic','Tyler','Samuel','Daniel','Jeremy'],
    'age':[20,25,15,10,30,65,35,18,23],
    'Product_ID':[101,0,106,0,103,104,0,0,107],
    'Purchased_Product':['Watch','NA','Oil','NA','Shoes','Smartphone','NA','NA','Laptop'],
    'City':['Mumbai','Delhi','Bangalore','Chennai','Chennai','Delhi','Kolkata','Delhi','Mumbai']
})
```

I want Price from 1st data frame to come in the merged dataframe. Common element being 'Product_ID'. Note that against product_ID 101, there are 2 prices - 299.00 and 9898.00. I want the later one to come in the merged data set i.e. 9898.0 (Since this is latest price)

Currently my code is not giving the right answer. It is giving both

```
customerpur = pd.merge(customer,product[['Price','Product_ID']], on="Product_ID", how = "left")
customerpur
```

```
    id  name    age Product_ID  Purchased_Product   City    Price
0   1   Olivia  20  101 Watch   Mumbai  299.0
1   1   Olivia  20  101 Watch   Mumbai  9898.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit timestamp so I assume the index is the order of the dataframe. You can drop duplicates at the end:

```
customerpur.drop_duplicates(subset = ['id'], keep = 'last')
```

result:

```
   id     name  age  Product_ID Purchased_Product       City    Price
1   1   Olivia   20         101             Watch     Mumbai   9898.0
2   2   Aditya   25           0                NA      Delhi      NaN
3   3     Cory   15         106               Oil  Bangalore    110.0
4   4  Isabell   10           0                NA    Chennai      NaN
5   5  Dominic   30         103             Shoes    Chennai   2999.0
6   6    Tyler   65         104        Smartphone      Delhi  14999.0
7   7   Samuel   35           0                NA    Kolkata      NaN
8   8   Daniel   18           0                NA      Delhi      NaN
9   9   Jeremy   23         107            Laptop     Mumbai  79999.0
```

Please note `keep = 'last'` argument since we are keeping only last price registered.
Deduplication should be done before merging if Yuo care about performace or dataset is huge:

```
product = product.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Product_ID'], keep = 'last')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful trick. If I want min, then I must sort (small to big) and then drop duplicates.

Comment: True. If the solution meets Your requirements consider accepting it as an aswer please.

Answer (score 1):

In your data frame there is no indicator of latest entry, so you might need to first remove the the first entry  for id `101` from `product` dataframe   as follows:

```
result_product = product.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product_ID'], keep='last')
```

It will keep the last entry based on `Product_ID` and you can do the merge as:

```
pd.merge(result_product, customer, on='Product_ID')
```